# Lenovo 3000 N100 WiFi not working even after driver update

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, lenovo

I have a Lenovo 3000N100 which has WiFi card/drives that are not working.

I have tested the card with Windows and it works. Tried un-installing the card in 12.04.1 and re-installing it even with a reboot and still no good.

Can anyone give me some help on this?

Answer (score 0):

in case you are running BCM4311 (to check run `lspci --vvnn | grep 14e4`)

try this:

(source bkratz ([ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2110823)))

---

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree 
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

---

works fine for me:)